# java servlet context cant load application.property file

Tags: java, servlets

I can't load `application.property` file for some reason. Here are my configurations:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm struggling for hours. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would use maven. Follow the [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and move the `application.properties` to `src/main/resources`.

Comment: I moved and it worked out, with classLoader(). thanks @Eliot. Do you have any idea what is this 'web' facet?

Comment: [Project facets](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcfacets.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you having any error messages in the output?
Try this one:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream(context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/application.properties")));
```